# Type Error - libvlc_video_set_logo_string

Tags: python, vlc, python-vlc

I am trying to display a logo using VideLogoOption from python-vlc

```
vlc.libvlc_video_set_logo_int(pi,vlc.VideoLogoOption.logo_enable,1)
vlc.libvlc_video_set_logo_string(pi,vlc.VideoLogoOption.logo_file,"Media/GUI.png")
```

Error: "argument 3: TypeError: wrong type" error
error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5lyk.png)

How to pass the file path correctly?

No documentation available

Comment: The documentation can be found here https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/

Answer (score 0):

## Set logo file path

```
logo_file_path = b"Media/GUI.png"  # Convert string to bytes
```

## Set the logo file path using libvlc_video_set_logo_string

```
vlc.libvlc_video_set_logo_string(pi, vlc.VideoLogoOption.logo_file, logo_file_path)
```

Make sure you convert the logo file path to bytes using b"..." notation because libVLC expects byte strings for paths.

Also, ensure that your VLC instance pi is correctly initialized and that you're using the correct VideoLogoOption constant (vlc.VideoLogoOption.logo_file) to specify the property you want to set